# Can I copy from one table to another in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I understand that [the COPY command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) imports lots of data very efficiently. But copying data from one table to another with [the INSERT command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INSERT_30.html) is slow. Is there a more efficient way to copy data from one table to the other? Or should I use [the UNLOAD command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) to unload the table into S3, then COPY it back from there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do `insert` into `new_table` (`select * from old_table`) .

But for bigger tables you should always do unload from old table then copy to new table.

The copy commands load data in parallel and it works fast. Unload also unloads data parallel. So unload and copy is good option to copy data from one table to other.

when you do copy command it automatically do the encoding ( compression ) for your data. When you do insert into ( `select * from` ) it will not do compression/encoding. You need to explicitly apply encoding types when you create new table.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to copy the records from `source_table` to `target_table`. Then query must be below

```
insert into target_table select * from source_table
```